# jquery masked input cursor carrot automatically in wrong spot

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, maskedinput

Hello I am using the http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin plug-in on a form. On desktop it works wonderfully but on some versions of Android it seems to place the cursor carrot to the left side of each character typed instead of the right side. On Android 6.0.1 in chrome and in the default browser this flaw exsits. On Android 7.X, it doesnt seem to. I dont have an older phone to test it with so Im unsure if this is an issue elsewhere. Do we think this is a bug in the digitalbush plug in or is it something else?

Example 
1) 1|_-____

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problems and changed masked input plugin to Robin Herbots. 
https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask